# GitHub: pulling and pushing project with my collaborator

Tags: github

I'm working on a project created by a friend. He created his project on Intellij and connected it to a Repository on GitHub. Committing and pushing works, but i (a collaborator) don't understand how i can pull the project from git, and doing merges/pushing/committing. Any help? I've watched plenty of tutorials, but everyone only address the problem of connecting a project to github.

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to clone the project?

Make sure you are actually under the collaborators and you can access it trough Github.
Then clone, steps [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cloning-repository.html#clone_project_from_main_screen).

After making changes go to the "VCS"->"Git"->"Commit", then "Push"

1. Then go to "VCS"->"Git"->"Merge Changes"
2. Select the branch you want to merge from
3. Resolve any conflicts and merge.